# obtain collection_name from parent's key in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

is it possible to ask parent for its refered collection_name based on one of its keys, 
lets say i have a parent db model and its key, can i know ths children who refer to this parent through collection name or otherwise

```
class Parent(db.Model):
  user = db.UserProperty()

class Childs(db.Model):
  refer = db.ReferenceProperty(Parent,collection_name='children')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

> [ReferenceProperty has another handy feature: back-references. When a model has a ReferenceProperty to another model, each referenced entity gets a property whose value is a Query that returns all of the entities of the first model that refer to it.](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html#References)

```
# To fetch and iterate over every Childs entity that refers to the
# Parent instance p:
for child in p.children:
# ...
```

Comment: This answer is correct to a point, except that in the specific example of the question, there is a collection_name set on the Childs' reference property.  

So in this case instance p has no childs_set, the references are in p.children

Comment: Oh, it seems the question was updated after I gave the answer. I've updated the answer to follow that change.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking "can I get the set of all the children that refer to a given parent".

In which case, yes you can, it's a property of the Parent class.

Assuming you have a Parent object p then the children that reference it will be in p.children

If you hadn't specified the collection_name on the ReferenceProperty they would be in p.childs_set

Check out the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty).